# Java logger framework with DB appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4net

I am looking for the a **java** logger framework like log4net(c#).

I need a logger with an appender like the AdoNetAppender in log4net that can insert logs into a self specified table and columns.

The logger will also have to have other appenders like file appenders.

I saw that log4j 2.0 is coming out soon, but still it doesn't seem to have db appender.

Logback's DB appender is also not good to me because it uses 3 tables that are proprietry to its design.

I have a .net service and a java application and I want them to write the logs to the same table in the database.

Thank you!

Comment: log4j has a JDBC Appender  check the example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_database.htm

Comment: How much load are you expecting? Logging the odd thing to a relational database is obviously fine, but if you're expecting heavy traffic then logging to an RDBMS is really, really bad idea, and something like writing to HDFS via Flume/Scribe might be more suitable.

Comment: @Deejay I am not expecting heavy load.

Answer (score 4):

log4net is based on log4j, not the other way 'round.

There's a DbAppender:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/receivers/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/db/DBAppender.html

Comment: Yes but the dbappender you are talking about is of log4j 1.2
Which is going to be legacy now, I am building a new project and I don't want to use frameworks that are going to be legacies..

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.